# how to delete only Windows Login in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using below code to delete SQL Logins

```
 declare @name  varchar(1000)     
 declare @xtype varchar(20)
 declare @sqlstring nvarchar(4000)

 declare SPViews_cursor cursor for
      SELECT  QUOTENAME(NAME) AS name
     FROM sys.server_principals     

 open SPViews_cursor
 fetch next from SPViews_cursor into @name     

 while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin
    set @sqlstring = 'drop LOGIN ' + @name
    exec sp_executesql @sqlstring
    set @sqlstring = ' '

    fetch next from SPViews_cursor into @name
 end

 close SPViews_cursor
 deallocate SPViews_cursor
```

but it is dropping all logins, I just need to drop Windows login so only SQL auth. can be possible. Any suggestion? And can this code be made shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT  QUOTENAME(NAME) AS name
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE type = 'U'
```

`U` means Window Login. You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

USE **type_desc** or **type** column to filter 'Windows Login'

```
SELECT  QUOTENAME(NAME) AS name
     FROM sys.server_principals
    where type_desc = 'WINDOWS_LOGIN'
```

Comment: I think if I wrote where type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN' then only sql logins will be delete , you mean to say where type_desc <> 'SQL_LOGIN'

Comment: i mean to say on **what column** you need to filter out.